# select multiple columns with aggregations

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with some fields (time, text, type). I want to build a query to return for every type the text that was introduced with the maximum value of time. Oracle has some restrictions and it is not simple to build the query without some tricks.

I am struggling to get the right query, can anyone help me with it?

```
TIME TEXT TYPE
--------------------------
03.05.2020 AA 2
02.04.2020 BB 2
01.04.2020 CC 1
```

I want a query that returns

```
03.05.2020 AA 2
01.04.2020 CC 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be using `DENSE_RANK, FIRST and LAST Analytic Functions` as

`MAX(time) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY time ) OVER( PARTITION BY type )`

```
WITH t2 AS
(
SELECT t.*, MAX(time) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY time ) OVER( PARTITION BY type ) 
            AS highest
  FROM t
)
SELECT time, text, type
  FROM t2
 WHERE highest = time
```

Through this method all the ties(repeating values for `time` for each `type` group) are listed.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=91fd8a8679a2d3e7bcb0bcf10ab7364f)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

First is to get the `max(TIME)` per `type`, then join it to your `tableA` to get other fields `(TEXT)`.

```
select * from tableA t
inner join 
     (select max(TIME) mt, type from tableA group by type) t1 on t1.mt=t.mt and t.type= t1.type
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number (or dense_rank):

```
select
    t.*
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by type_column order by time_column desc) rn
    from tbl t
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: `dense_rank()` is a better option than `row_number()` since `dense_rank()` returns all the tie records for time for each type whenever multiple maximum time values exist for any.